# Swiftui, how to change view's shadow radius when tap

Tags: swiftui, shadow

```
Text("xxx")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 48)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .shadow(radius: 6)
                        .onTapGesture(perform: {

                        })
```

How can I change shadow radius to 0 when I press and recovery 6 when finish press

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple, just add a ternary operator to shadow, which depends of state var

Code example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var press: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("xxx")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .shadow(radius: press ? 0 : 6)
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                withAnimation {
                    press.toggle()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom `ButtonStyle`, you can respond when the press starts/ends. Unfortunately, `onTapGesture` alone doesn't give access to the state of the press:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("xxx")
        }
        .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
        .frame(height: 48)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}


struct CustomButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .shadow(radius: configuration.isPressed ? 0 : 6)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
@State var press: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    Text("xxx")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .shadow(radius: press ? 0 : 6)
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                withAnimation {
                    press.toggle()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    withAnimation {
                        press.toggle()
                    }
                }
            })
}
```

`